# Notebook in VSCode not displaying output

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've been working on relatively small dataframe in notebook running in VSCode. Display has been working fine but on one cell now just displays a blank space. If I copy the output into a text editor it appears correctly. Also tried copying to new cell and print but to no available. Also tried resetting kernel. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Oops. Worked after restarting VSCode